# Extracting error in python

Tags: python, zip

It did extract but I got this error (google didnt help me) What is that and how to fix that?

`data = self._decompressor.decompress(data, n)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type`

Comment: "Extract" is an odd word to use to decompression. What kind of file is it?

Comment: It's a zip file

Comment: Why are you using the `zlib` (gzip compression) library instead of `zipfile`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not. 
` 
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('MyFile.zip', 'r')
zf.extractall(pwd=me)
`

Comment: ever figure this out?